# JS To Submit Button Gravity Form

Tags: gravity-forms-plugin

I have the js below that "clicks" a button's action when executed (with a class of "wpc-button-1161") that I want to run when the submit button on gravity form is clicked. How to I do that?

`$(function(){
    window.location.href = $('.wpc-button-1161').attr('href');
});`

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. Make sure the gravity form has ajax="true" in the short code and the js below. Example has two forms with buttons with classes of wpc-button-1161 and wpc-button-1168.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

    jQuery(document).on('gform_confirmation_loaded', function(event, formId){
        if(formId == 1) {
window.location.href = $('.wpc-button-1161').attr('href');
        } else if(formId == 2) {
window.location.href = $('.wpc-button-1168').attr('href');
        }
    });

})
```